# ESLint - How to override extended file severity

Tags: javascript, eslint, static-code-analysis

ESLint - How to override extended file severity?
Example: I can't disable indent errors.
Base configuration:

```
  "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
```

My eslintrc configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    extends: "./baseConfig.js",
    rules: {
        "indent": [
            "warn",
            "tab"
        ],
    }
};
```

but I'm still getting errors for the indent rule. I also tried:

```
rules: {
    "indent": 0
}
```

but again got indent errors. what is wrong here?

location of project at 
/git/projectX

structure:

```
Project
    index.js
    package.json
    eslintrc.js
    baseConfig.js
```

Comment: Can you tell me location of this file on your machine? User folder or project folder, also can you give directory structure of your project

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to change `eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.js`.

Also do you have an `eslintConfig` field in package.json?  That could also interfere.

Comment: .eslintrc.js didn't help and I don't have any eslintConfig in my package.json :/

Comment: What happens when you go `node_modules/.bin/eslint -c .eslintrc.js [filename]` ?

Comment: also could you show your package.json file (scripts section) and baseConfig.js maybe?